# Android emulator crash on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

When I am running a project the emulator is taking too much of time and all of sudden it is crashing. My set-up is MAC OS X version 10.7.3, eclipse indigo, android-sdk 4.0.3.

I dont have any audio devices connected to my MAC system, as few of you have suggested to remove the USB audio plug before emulator boots up and plug it again when the emulator has fully loaded.

On eclipse am getting this error msg : `emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'org.ingenyous.basicphonegap.BasicPhonegapActivity activity launch'!`

And there is a pop-up msg from mac which says : `emulator-arm quit unexpectedly`.
Earlier everything was working fine. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this same issue on Mac OSX 10.8.2 running the latest updates of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your 4.0.3 (sdk and ARM system image) is updated to the latest release.

Comment: where can i find th ARM system image. Am new to android dev

Comment: hey i tried to update it got failed and show this msg :Failed to fetch URL http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml/addon.xml, reason: Connection to http://innovator.samsungmobile.com refused

Comment: arm system image is in the same list under Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Hey Tarun Maheshwari, i hv done as u said but to no avail. Am still facing the same problem. Firstly, the emulator is taking 5-6 mins to load then its crashing